# Is the nullspace of the product of two square matrices a subset of the nullspace of one of them?

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, alternative-proof

Suppose $A$ and $P$ are two nxn matrices. Is $ N(PA) \subseteq N(A)$ ? How would you prove that, or disprove that?

 
I tried to prove this and realized that if I do not know if $A$ and $P$ are nonsingular, then I cannot use the simple proof utilizing $ P^{-1} $. 
 
What I reasoned was that I have two cases for $ A\vec{x}=0 $, where I have $ \vec{x} = 0 $, and $ \vec{x} \neq 0 $.

Where $ \vec{x} = 0 $, since the only solution here is the trivial solution, we know that $PA$ must be nonsingular, hence both $A$ and $P$ are nonsingular. Letting $ \vec{x}\in N(PA) $. Then $ PA\vec{x} = 0$. We can show that $ P^{-1}PA\vec{x} = P^{-1}0 \Rightarrow A\vec{x} = 0$. Therefore, $ \vec{x}\in N(A) $.

Where $ \vec{x} \neq 0 $, I reasoned that either $A$ and $P$ are nonsingular, or that $A$ or $P$ is singular. 
If $A$ and $P$ are nonsingular, then the proof that $ N(PA) \subseteq N(A) $ is pretty straightforward like the last one. But if they are not both nonsingular, then we do not necessarily know if the rank is preserved under the product of $A$ and $P$. If the $ rank(PA) \neq rank(A) $, then they cannot be the same subspace.

Comment: Hint: Can you find two non-zero square matrices whose products is zero?

Comment: Better yet, can you find a nonzero matrix whose square is zero?

Comment: Pick any $x\ne0$. Pick a matrix $A$ such that $y=Ax\ne0$. Then pick a matrix $P$ such that $Py=0$. Now $x\in N(PA)$ but $x\not\in N(A)$.